# Limit People Search Scope to Colleagues Only

Tags: search, search-scope, people-search

I'm trying to define a scope down to just a person's colleagues but can't find the property I would use to create the rule.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Search in SharePoint 2010 supports following Ranking algorithms these being Default ranking model (Main Results Default), Expertise Social, Distance ranking model, High Proximity ranking, Main People Social, Distance, Expertise model, **Name Social Distance** (you need to target) and Name model. By default the first approximation of 3 pages are showing Colleagues.

This command in PowerShell `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingModel` gets all ranking available on their Identifiers. Programatically you can find an example here http://johanolivier.blogspot.com/2011/05/improve-sharepoint-search-relevance.html

Via Web-UI (unless you use FAST) you don't get to change this.

Not sure exactly, but I would target creating a custom Search Scope and combined with various User Attributes (e.g. Department, Same Manager) probably could reach it.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius